# Replace words on php keeping case

Tags: php, regex

How can replace some '*whole words*' for anothers keeping the same caps (lower, first, or all) and singular/plural of source word?

If i have this:

```
$text="This is a text about animals Word1 and Letters1. 
We also talk about animals words2, letter2 and WORDS3, LETTERS3. 
And text woRd4, LEtter4 and LETTEr5 and wordpress";
```

And

```
$replacements=['word'=>'cat','letter'=>'dog'];
```

I hope to get:

```
$text="This is a text about animals Cat1 and Dogs1. 
We also talk about animals cats2, dog2 and CATS3, DOGS3. 
And text woRd4, LEtter4 and LETTEr5 and wordpress";
```

**In summary:**

I have a word and a replacement: For example, 'letter' and 'dog', and I want to:

1. Change all words that match that word in lowercase by the lowercase replacement: 'letter' by 'dog'.
2. Change all words that match that word in capital letters with the replacement in capital letters: 'LETTER' by 'DOG'.
3. Change all words that match that word with the first letter in capital letters by replacing it with the first letter in capital letters: 'Letter' by 'Dog'.

And I want to do this using only one combination in the array, instead of the three possible, because the array is read from a configuration file:

I want to write this in the config:

`$replacements=['word'=>'cat','letter'=>'dog'];`

And not this:

`$replacements=['word'=>'cat','Word'=>'Cat','WORD'=>'CAT','letter'=>'dog',
'Letter'=>'Dog','LETTER'=>'DOG'];`

**The best solution that I found is:**

```
$text="This is a text about animals Word1 and Letters1. 
    We also talk about animals words2, letter2 and WORDS3, LETTERS3. 
    And text woRd4, LEtter4 and LETTEr5";

function replace($replacements, $text)
{
    $_replacements=[];

    // Add the three possible patterns
    foreach($replacements as $search=>$replace)
    {
        $_replacements[strtolower($search)]=strtolower($replace);
        $_replacements[strtoupper($search)]=strtoupper($replace);
        $_replacements[ucfirst(strtolower($search))]=ucfirst(strtolower($replace));
    }

    return str_replace(array_keys($_replacements), array_values($_replacements), $text);
}

echo(replace($replacements, $text));
```

This solution, however, replace WordPress by CatPress :(

**Is there a better and / or more efficient solution? Any solution using regex?**

**PS:** You can test my code here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aa37de86c01228b82aee0622c6b17c5cf9f08241

**PS:** This line: `And text woRd4, LEtter4 and LETTEr5` is to indicate that all other possible of case combinations are not important.

PS: The similar questions I have found in stackoverflow are about formatting and highlighting and its solution is not applicable to this case (or I have not known how to apply it)

Comment: your 3rd line is confusing, 1st and 2nd are replaced except 3rd? what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Your target is replace the word ignore upper and lower? but why your LEtter4 isnt replaced.

Comment: How can we keep the case if the replacement has more or less letters ?

Comment: I understand that handling all possible combinations of capital letters and lowercase letters is impossible. Especially if you change the number of letters between search and replacement. That's why I have chosen only three patterns or combinations and the third line (`And text woRd4, LEtter4 and LETTEr5`) is to indicate that all other combinations are not important

Comment: I would have appreciated all the extra information you added after an hour, especially the requirement to **not** have a larger lookup array, before working on a now (and forever) deleted working solution. But really; what does it matter if the lookup is a bit longer? If it works - it works. It's not as if the server will overload and melt from a few extra array elements. Have you heard of [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @FredGandt, I apologize for not having added that information before. Precisely after seeing your answer with the proposed solution and the other comments, I have been aware that I needed to clarify my ideas and needs and expose them again. In fact, your answer is the one that has led me to the solution I just added. So I thank you for it.
I do not care about the size of the array, but it has to be generated dynamically as I show in the example.
Here in Spain, it's 5:00 in the morning and, perhaps, not the best time to write a question, ouch!

Comment: `$replacements` has to be generated dynamically? That would contradict your desire to write it in your config, but moving on - you actually want a generic function to perform the task of replacing text whilst maintaining case that accepts **any** `$search->$replace` array it's given. If it weren't 4:15am, I'd start again right now, but will come back tomorrow instead. Good night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A version that deals with irregular plurals:

```
$text = 'This is a text about animals, Children, Word1 and Letters1. 
We also talk about animals words2, letter2 and WORDS3, LETTERS3. 
And text woRd4, LEtter4 and LETTEr5';

// replacements
$regular = [ 'word' => 'cat', 'letter' => 'dog', 'animal' => ['child', 'children'] ];
$nonregular = [ 'child' => 'animal', 'children' => 'animals' ];

$result = preg_replace_callback('~[a-z]+(?:(?<=(s)))?~i', function ($m) use ($regular, $nonregular) {
    $lower = strtolower($m[0]);
    $rep = $m[0];
    if ( isset($nonregular[$lower]) ) {
        $rep = $nonregular[$lower];
    } elseif ( isset($regular[$lower]) ) {
        $rep = is_array($regular[$lower]) ? $regular[$lower][0] : $regular[$lower];
    } elseif ( isset($m[1]) ) {
        $sing = substr($lower, 0, -1);
        if ( isset($regular[$sing]) )
            $rep = is_array($regular[$sing]) ? $regular[$sing][1] : $regular[$sing] . 's';
    } else {
        return $rep;
    }

    if ( $m[0] == $lower )
        return $rep;
    elseif ($m[0] == strtoupper($lower) )
        return strtoupper($rep);
    elseif ( $m[0] == ucfirst($lower) )
        return ucfirst($rep);

    return $rep;
}, $text);

echo $text, PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL, $result;
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/rMnPI)

Feel free to organize the replacement array with plurals categories and to write a unicode version.

Comment: Thank you. I really liked the possibility of manage irregular plurals.

Comment: @JuanAntonioTubío: thanks, but note that the support of irregular plurals is actually very basic since you have to include each forms of the words in the non-regular array. It's better to write a structure in which words with the same plural termination are together (the most possible), something like: `[ 's' => ['wd1'=>'rp1','wd2'=>'rp2'...], 'es'=>['wd3'=>'rp3'...], ...]` and eventually build an index to retrieve them quickly, or to use a dictionary to automatically build a hash with all the forms.